# Running Java program 24X7

Tags: java, windows, swing

I want to run a a java program on a remote computer 24 x 7.

i have included everything in try catch blocks so that it does not end because of Exceptions.

But program is currently running in my eclipse IDE.

How should i proceed .
Should i make a SWING GUI and convert into exe that keeps running.

Is there any way in which the program runs every time computer is running .(may be as a service)?

Comment: Of course, this is what app servers were born to do.  Swing GUI?  .exe?  No, write a service and a browser based UI and you're done.

Comment: the program is standalone which updates my  remote DB .It consists of 2-3 threads and UDP networking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JavaServiceWrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html) is a good utility to wrap a a Java program as a service.

Note in particular its [restart capability](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html#reliability). You can configure this to restart the service upon exit, or if given messages appear in the logs/output (e.g. OutOfMemoryErrors etc. - this is *particularly* useful since the app becomes unresponsive but hasn't exited)

Comment: I use JSW and it catches memory exceptions. If the app runs out of memory you might try monitoring it using JVisualVM, and if the permgen is running out of space, increase it.  Alternatively, if its the heap running out of memory, then moving to a 64-bit jvm with a high memory max can, in many cases, completely solve that issue.

Comment: In case anyone is looking to use JSW on Win64 without a commercial license, Sonatype has posted binaries built from the v3.2.3 source that is under the old non-restrictive license. https://github.com/sonatype/jsw-binaries

Answer (score 1):

You can run Java without IDE through Command Line Prompt. i.e., Bash shell for Unix/Linux/Mac, cmd for Windows.

Steps:

1. Compile your java source code by `javac Example.java ...`
2. Run you app by `java Example`

And for sure, you can write a `shell script` or `.bat` which contain the `java Example` command, and ask the system to execute it everything after the system boots up.

For more info, checkout http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html

Answer (score 1):

You can package it as a executable jar, and then just launch it using java -jar YourProg.jar.  If you have several library dependencies, you can use [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) to package everything into a single jar.

As for launching it every time the computer starts, depending on your version of windows, you can use some of the tools from the MS Resource Toolkit  such as [srvany](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) to launch it at startup.